# Subclassing UISelectMany to create a custom JSF Component

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I need to create a custom Component with JSF 2.0 (not composite component), that is similar to a SelectManyCheckbox, but has a different UI. I try to do this by subclassing UISelectMany and creating a new custom Renderer.

What I don't understand is, how is the input data on the client passed through the Component into the Bean. There must be a way to collect the http params from the POST, put it in a List and set the List in the Bean.

*edited*

What I already tried is similar to this:

```
public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    if ((context == null) || (component == null)) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
   }
   MapComponent map = (MapComponent) component;
   String key = getName(context, map);
   String value = (String)context.getExternalContext().
       getRequestParameterMap().get(key);
   if (value != null)
      map.setCurrent(value);
   }
}
```

I can see in the debugger, that my http-params are fetched correctly. I can also see, that my custom Converter will be called after that. But the values do not reach the Bean. But I can see a unspecific validation error in the log.
After reading some tutorials on the net I still don't understand how this works. There must be some glue-code, that takes the converted value and passes it to the setter in the Bean. Does anybody know how this works?

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *There must be a way to collect the http params from the POST, put it in a List and set the List in the Bean.*

This is normally to be done in [`decode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html#decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) method of the [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html) class. In case of [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net), it's the `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer` class. Just [download](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html) the source and peek in there how it's to be done.

*Basically*, you just grab the request parameter values associated with the component's client ID as parameter name and then set it as submitted value by the [`UIInput#setSubmittedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#setSubmittedValue%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    ((UIInput) component).setSubmittedValue(context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterValuesMap().get(component.getClientId(context)));
}
```

*(of course you need to do some validation beforehand; again, check the original source code)*

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I think the validation might be the problem. I implemented a decode() and getConvertedValue() and I can see in debugmode that they are called. But after that I see a validation error in the log. I did'nt find out why this error is raised... or how the validation works...

Comment: What's the message of the validation error? The infamous "Value not valid"?

Comment: Yes, exactly... apperently I am making some well knowen mistakes ? ;-)    Maybe UISelectMany checks if all selected values are part of the complete valuelist from which the values are selected. But currently I have only the selected values. I wasn't able to see in the jsf sources where this happens, yet.

Comment: The "Value not valid" is not a problem in the component. It's a problem in the enduser's managed bean / view code. It will be caused when the view code and/or the managed bean does not provide exactly the same list of values during the request of processing the form submit as it was during the request of displaying the initial form. The solution is rather trivial: if the bean is request scoped, you need to prepare that list in the (post)constructor of the bean, or if the list needs to be prepared during an action method, put the bean in the view scope instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Own class which extends javax.faces.component.UISelectMany

```
class MySelectMany extends javax.faces.component.UISelectMany
{

//over-ride methods of javax.faces.component.UISelectMany


// this method is inherited from javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase. You can use this method to set the rendererType

public void setRendererType(java.lang.String rendererType)
{

// custom rendering
}

}
```